# Passing method as templated argument C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, parameter-passing

I have this structure:

```
class A {
  public:
     int setI(int i){_i = i;}
  private:
     int _i;
}
class B {
  public:
     int setZ(int z){_z = z;}
  private:
     int _z;
}
class C : public A, public B {};
```

Then I want to call methods setI or setZ from templated function elsewhere

Something like:

```
template <class P>
void myMethod(P &myclass, void (P::*setter) (const int)) const
   {
         int var = 9;
         (myclass.*setter)(var);
   }
```

I use this method like this:

```
   C c;
   mymethod(c, &C::setI);
```

It fails because setI is defined in A not in C, is there any way to pass method from class A or class B following this structure?

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It fails in part because `C::setI` is `protected`. Make it accessible to that piece of code by making `C::setI` `public`.

Another part is `void(P::*setter)(const int)` is not the type of `C::setI`. It should rather be `int(P::*setter)(int)`.

Alternatively, pass a lambda to `myMethod`, it saves you from having to spell out the member function pointer type and it can be more efficient:

```
template<class P, class Setter>
void myMethod(P &myclass, Setter set) {
    int var = 9;
    set(myclass, var);
}

int main() {
    C c;
    myMethod(c, [](C& c, int a) { c.setI(a); }); 
}
```

---

You may also like to enable warnings (`-Wall -Wextra -Werror` for `gcc` and `clang`) so that compilation fails when a function forgets to return a value, like `setI` and `setZ` do.

Comment: Thanks, I will modify the example because event setting both setters to public fails

Comment: @RuLoViC Updated the answer for you.